# Nextjs 13 app folder not redirect to 500 page if error was thrown

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have api route.ts and there i return status 500

`return NextResponse.json(data, { status: 500, });`
And in my component where fetch happens, i have try catch, but nothing happens.
I tried to throw error in my route.ts but also nothing happens.
So my question is, how i can handle 500 error and redirect user to a error.tsx page?

I tried throw error in my component. Tried in route.ts but nothing.

Comment: A 500 status code does not throw an error when fetching. Use the `ok` and `status` property of your fetch's response to determine if the request was successful.

Comment: Yes, but how and where i should throw error or what in order to redirect customer to error page?
For example to reproduce with fake fetch response, how i can redirect him?

Comment: Return a 500 error status code from your API, throw inside your server component if a error was received during fetch and add a [error.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling) file for your segment.

Comment: Thanks, i have error.js and i return 500 from route.ts to my Context Provider. And i use client component. I can not use server component because of MUI and also i get functions to call from my AuthProvider.

Comment: Then throw an uncaught error in your client component. error.js will handle it anyway.

Comment: Throwing and nothing happens... :( This is why i came here to ask... 
Maybe it is because i have [locale], but i have error.js and global-error.js in app folder and they should handle it

Comment: Ok finally i found the problem, is because of formik submitForm() if i throw error in other place, for example useEffect() all good. Thanks for you replies :)